# How to make visible fixed position element when window is being resized

Tags: resize, window, position, fixed

I have element with id="fixed" and following css style:

`#fixed { position: fixed;  width: 100%; background: #444; height: 70px;}`

Within this element is other element with class="inner" and following css style:

`#fixed .inner {width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto;}`

The element #fixed MUST be fixed position, in other words the element #fixed MUST be always at top of the page.

Live example [here](http://www.pavelhanys.cz/nahledy/test-page.html).

When I resize the window under 800px (1000-width of right menu), right menu disappeared and no scrollbar is available.

Thank you in advance for any idea how this problem could be solved.

Chavier

Comment: You can give your right menu a fixed position with `right:100px;`.

Comment: Note that a site like http://jsfiddle.net helps everybody test without copying what you put on your personal site.

Comment: Although the giving right menu a fixed position does solved problem when window size is thiner than 1000px, but when window is wider than 1000px right menu is position to the right edge of window, while it is needed to be position to the right edge of element class="inner" (something like float right). JSFiddle is a great tool, but i think for this kind of problem (resize window) is not appropriate, because you need to see page in its whole size insted of small container. Any another idea to solve the problem?